# ASP.NET HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() is not serializable

Tags: asp.net, stream, httpclient

Good day.

I'm trying to make a GET request to an API. The request returns an array of Phone records.

Here's the Phone class:

```
public enum OS { Android, IOS, WindowsPhone }
public enum MANIFACTURER { Apple, Nokia, Samsung }

public class Phone
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public MANIFACTURER Manifacturer { get; set; }
    public OS OS { get; set; }
    public int RAM { get; set; }
    public int Storage { get; set; }
    public double ScreenSize { get; set; }
    public double CameraResolution { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Using HttpClient, the direct return of GetStreamAsync contains the desired data but is not extractable as List (I get a an array of null valued phone records):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<object> GetPhonesAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        var response = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:50002/samsung-api/samsungphones/");

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Phone>));
        List<Phone> phones = serializer.ReadObject(response) as List<Phone>;

        //return response;
        return phones;
    }
```

The return is:

```
[{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":0,"model":null,"price":0.0,"manifacturer":0,"os":0,"ram":0,"storage":0,"screenSize":0.0,"cameraResolution":0.0,"isAvailable":false}]
```

Now if I return "response" instead of "phones" I get:

```
[{"id":1,"model":"Galaxy J5 Prime","price":569.0,"os":0,"ram":2,"storage":16,"screenSize":5.0,"cameraResolution":13.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":2,"model":"Galaxy J3 Pro","price":649.0,"os":0,"ram":2,"storage":16,"screenSize":5.0,"cameraResolution":13.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":3,"model":"Galaxy J7 Core","price":664.0,"os":0,"ram":2,"storage":16,"screenSize":5.5,"cameraResolution":13.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":4,"model":"Galaxy A3","price":854.0,"os":0,"ram":2,"storage":16,"screenSize":4.7,"cameraResolution":13.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":5,"model":"Galaxy A5","price":1139.0,"os":0,"ram":3,"storage":32,"screenSize":5.2,"cameraResolution":16.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":6,"model":"Galaxy A7","price":1329.0,"os":0,"ram":3,"storage":32,"screenSize":5.7,"cameraResolution":16.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":7,"model":"Galaxy S7 Edge","price":1799.0,"os":0,"ram":4,"storage":32,"screenSize":5.5,"cameraResolution":12.0,"isAvailable":false},{"id":8,"model":"Galaxy S7","price":1899.0,"os":0,"ram":4,"storage":32,"screenSize":5.1,"cameraResolution":12.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":9,"model":"Galaxy S8","price":2469.0,"os":0,"ram":4,"storage":64,"screenSize":5.8,"cameraResolution":12.0,"isAvailable":true},{"id":10,"model":"Galaxy Note 8","price":2849.0,"os":0,"ram":6,"storage":64,"screenSize":6.3,"cameraResolution":12.0,"isAvailable":true}]
```

Please point out how I can correctly extract the Phone objects from the stream.
Thank you kindly.

Comment: How is `Phone` class defined?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek added.

Comment: ..try to return phones without awaiting response?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since there is no solution and I have experienced similar,  here is how I resolved the null object.

The problem is when you use the DataContractJsonSerializer from Runtime.Serialization, the associated model class must have the appropriate properties, like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "productId")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

The `DataContract` property is used on the model class and the `DataMember` property is used on its variable(s), matching the equivalent JSON key. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Phone")]
public class Phone
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "manifacturer")]
    public MANIFACTURER Manifacturer { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "os")]
    public OS OS { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ram")]
    public int RAM { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "storage")]
    public int Storage { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "screenSize")]
    public double ScreenSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "cameraResolution")]
    public double CameraResolution { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "isAvailable")]
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller code should now work as intended, returning a populated list of Phone objects.

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data